# Linux PPP : how to debug disconnects with exit code = 16?

Tags: debian, modem, ppp, mobile, wvdial

I'm using `pppd` and `wvdial` on my ARM Linux embedded system. I have a CDMA modem connected via a serial port and am connecting to the Verizon network. I am seeing that several times per day `pppd` exits with exit code 16 (see exact message from log below). How do I work out what is causing these disconnects? In particular what does the `LCP terminated by peer` message indicate?

```
Feb 18 12:31:04 ts7600-47aad3 pppd[3242]: LCP terminated by peer
Feb 18 12:31:04 ts7600-47aad3 pppd[3242]: Connect time 0.6 minutes.
Feb 18 12:31:04 ts7600-47aad3 pppd[3242]: Sent 1044 bytes, received 0 bytes.
Feb 18 12:31:04 ts7600-47aad3 pppd[3242]: restoring old default route to eth0 [1
92.168.98.1]
Feb 18 12:31:07 ts7600-47aad3 pppd[3242]: Connection terminated.
Feb 18 12:31:07 ts7600-47aad3 pppd[3242]: Modem hangup
Feb 18 12:31:07 ts7600-47aad3 pppd[3242]: Exit.
Feb 18 12:31:07 ts7600-47aad3 wvdial: Disconnecting at Tue Feb 18 12:31:07 2014
Feb 18 12:31:07 ts7600-47aad3 wvdial: The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up t
he phone (exit code = 16)
Feb 18 12:31:07 ts7600-47aad3 wvdial: man pppd explains pppd error codes in more
 detail.
```

Comment: you should enable debug options and you'll able to see what was the reason of the hangup.

Comment: yes added debug options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Important:** you can always override your default options with local options.

from `man pppd`

```
   /etc/ppp/options
          System default options for pppd, read before user default 
          options or command-line options.
```

and also

```
~/.ppprc
/etc/ppp/options.ttyname
/etc/ppp/peers
```

you should enable debug options (sometimes also kdebug)

```
   debug  Enables connection debugging facilities.  If this option
   is given, pppd will log the contents of all control packets  sent  
   or  received  in a readable form.  The packets are logged 
   through syslog with facility daemon and level debug.  This 
   information can be directed to  a  file  by  setting  
   up  /etc/syslog.conf  appropriately  (see  sys-log.conf(5)).
```

your exit codes

```
   EXIT STATUS
      16     The link was terminated by the modem hanging up.
```

and so on.

Your error is `LCP terminated by peer`
there are several links which explain how to fix it:

`you'll need to pass "refuse-eap" option to pppd.`
   [ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1095546)

[lcp_term_authentication](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#lcp_term_authentication)

or simply check your credentials.

Comment: I've got debugging turned on in my options.  Do you know what the message "LCP terminated by peer" indicates?  I'd like to find the root cause of the disconnects.

Comment: Looks like my problem was a hardware problem, power supply was occasionally cutting out causing the disconnect.

Comment: Yeah, reason for this are often weak capacitors. With a little soldering skills you can replace them.